# Erro ao importar projecto maven no Eclipse: No marketplace entries found to handle

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee, maven

Sou novo na programação JavaWeb e ao instalar o eclipse e importar meu projeto criado pelo Maven, acusa o erro abaixo:

> No marketplace entries found to handle maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.

O que fazer para resolver esta questão?

Este é o `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.projetojee</groupId>
    <artifactId>programarjavaweb</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>React.js Blank Project (from https://github.com/making/maven-reactjs-blank)</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>gulp</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="Gulp!" />
                                <exec executable="gulp">
                                    <arg value="build" />
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/resources</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>dest</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Você está importando como projeto maven ou como projeto do eclipse? Qual a versão do eclipse? Se possível, inclua o trecho do `pom.xml` da configuração deste plugin que apresentou erro.

Comment: Esta la, o eclipse é a versão mais nova 3.3JavaEE @BrunoCésar

Comment: Ok, já incluo uma resposta para você

Comment: No projeto não incluiu as duas partes mais importantes do maven.

Comment: Tranquilo, só com isto consigo simular aqui e já incluo uma "solução" para você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este erro acontece por que o plugin do maven no eclipse (`m2eclipse`) não ter suporte ao `goal` `run` no *life cycle* definido, `generate-resources`. Para importar, você pode fazer de duas formas:

- desconsiderar a mensagem e importar, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: Desconsiderar erro e importar projeto]

- adicionar o seguinte trecho ao seu `pom.xml` (caso já tenha algum *plugin* gerenciado, inclua apenas a parte do *plugin*, sem `pluginManagement` e `plugins`):

```xml
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.8,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Mesmo se utilizar a primeira abordagem você poderá incluir o trecho da segunda abordagem ao seu `pom.xml` para que não seja apresentado erro para você.

Este plugin não faz nada, não tem efeito nenhum em outras IDEs ou pela linha de comando, apenas informar ao `m2eclipse` que é para desconsiderar este ciclo de vida, não sendo apresentado o erro.

Quais as consequências disto? Bom, como o `m2eclipse` não dá suporte à estes ciclos de vida você não conseguirá executá-los usando o maven embutido do eclipse, mas não irá interferir em nada no seu build em si. Caso dê algum impacto e você precise executar este `goal` no eclipse, uma alternativa é alterar o *life cycle* para outro, como por exemplo `prepare-package`, ficando assim:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>gulp</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <echo message="Gulp!" />
                    <exec executable="gulp">
                        <arg value="build" />
                    </exec>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**EDIÇÃO**: incluindo `pom.xml` completo

Considerando o `pom.xml` incluindo na pergunta, ele completo e alterado ficaria da seguinte forma:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.projetojee</groupId>
    <artifactId>programarjavaweb</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>React.js Blank Project (from https://github.com/making/maven-reactjs-blank)</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>gulp</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="Gulp!" />
                                <exec executable="gulp">
                                    <arg value="build" />
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/resources</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>dest</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.8,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Qual parte do código adiciono as informações, teria como colocaro pom.xml com todas as alterações ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues incluído, veja se te ajuda agora

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração.

Comment: So tenho mais uma duvida, é normal não aparecer o pacote no src/main/java, porque aqui ele esta vazio.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues mesmo quando não não há pacotes nesta pasta o eclipse exibe, lá em *Java Build Path*. No entanto, se não existir tal diretório pode ser por isto que não tenha apresentado, ele não é um diretório obrigatório, apenas padrão

Comment: A sim, minha pergunta, é porque estou iniciando meus estudos, e estou acompanhando uma aula virtual, onde a do professor funcionou tudo legal, porem a minha não está da mesma forma.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues tranquilo, qualquer dúvida só perguntar =D